# Solr numeric rangeQuery returns only partial results

Tags: solr, range-query

I've implemented Solr and I am attempting to range query on a field and I am getting only half the expected results. Anyone have any ideas as to what might be going on here?

example:

`myData = {
  item1: {
    my_field: 98
  },
  item2: {
    my_field: 99
  },
  item3: {
    my_field: 99
  },
  item4: {
    my_field: 99
  },
  item5: {
    my_field: 99
  },
  item6: {
    my_field: 99
  }
}`

Range Queries:

- `[99 TO 99]` // returns 1/5 expected results: item2
- `[99 TO 100]` //returns 2/5: item2, item3
- `[99 TO 101]` // returns 2/5: item2, item3
- `[99 TO 102]` // Finally returns 5/5: item2, item3, item4, item5, item6

Comment: What is the field type for my_value?  Is it like this?   <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>  this gives a good guide for range queries: https://www.slideshare.net/VadimKirilchuk/numeric-rangequeries

Comment: All I can tell is, it's stored as indexed integer. It looks like we are using some sort of dynamic schema generation based of field name format. Thanks though @binarymax . Will update once I find out more information.

Comment: How are the actual documents structured? Are these six documents with just a single `my_field`? Is the `my_field` actually defined as an integer (the schema browser should tell you this)? Integers as string tokens might give you behaviour like this.